# Regex - Lookup number but exclude if specific words are in the document

Tags: regex

I'm not sure this is possible to do but… I am trying to search for a number string.  I have a working pattern to do that but if certain words appear in the document along with the number I do not want it detected.

For example I’m searching for a 9 digit number in all documents but if the document contains the word test, testing, false… etc. I do not want the 9 digit number to be caught.

Specifically I’m searching for SSN’s but I don’t want the SSN caught if certain keywords are in the document including excel spreadsheets.

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely possible. How to do it exactly depends on the regex engine, so you need to add this info in case the following solution doesn't work for you:

```
(?s)\A(?!.*\b(?:test|testing|false)\b).*(\b\d{9}\b)
```

After the match, the nine-digit number will be in backreference no. 1.

**Explanation:**

```
(?s)                    # Dot-matches-all mode (use (?m) in Ruby!)
\A                      # Start of string
(?!                     # Assert that it's impossible to match...
 .*                     #  any string, followed by
 \b                     #  a word boundary (start of word),
 (?:test|testing|false) #  one of these keywords (don't capture it),
 \b                     #  a word boundary (end of word).
)
.*                      # Match any string until...
(\b\d{9}\b)             # an entire nine-digit number.
```

Comment: It's perl regex that I am using.  When I tested the pattern it seems like the document had to have test, testing and false in it for it to be captured.